# Why is jQuery transforming the URL of my AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to load chat messages with a javascript jQuery function using AJAX.  I am new to jQuery and this is my first time using AJAX along with it.  I call the function from my html with a script tag.  My HTML source appears to be correct, but I get 404 not found error from my AJAX call.  The URL the error returns adds some unfamiliar numbers to the end of it and I can't figure out why....

Here is my HTML

```
<script>

            load_chat("http://localhost/basecommand/index.php/ajax/chat/conversations/2");

    </script>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function load_chat(ajax_url) {
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: ajax_url,
                            dataType: "xml",
                            cache: false,
                    }
                    ).done(
                        function(){
                            $("#chat_messages").fadeOut();
                            $(xml).find('message').each(function(){
                               $("#chat_messages").append(
                               '<div class="block1"><h1>' +
                               $(this).find("author_name").text() + '</h1><p>' +
                               $(this).find("content").text() + '</p><h3>About ' +
                               $(this).find("datesent").text() + ' ago.</h3></div>'
                                )
                            });
                            $("#chat_messages").fadeIn();
                        }
                    );

        };
```

The error that is being returned:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlobY.jpg

The URL works absolutely fine when I access it directly. No errors on the page, either.

Comment: what happend if you access that URL directly?

Comment: Those numbers are a cache breaker.  This isn't the problem.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I did not post that question.  And the URL works absolutely fine when accessed directly.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Evan isn't saying *you* had posted that question; he means the subject matter in that question is the same as this. Which is echoed by Daedalus, that the additional element on the end is merely a GET parameter, and does not affect how your request is routed. If you're saying the URL works when accessed directly (through the browser's address bar), try it with the `?_1393...` stuff at the end; it should still work. If not, you may have something odd (admittedly I can't imagine what that might be...) interfering with your routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checklist:

1. The error say that the URL is not good...  Check at the browser if `http://localhost/basecommand/index.php/ajax/chat/conversations/2` exist. Ok, you say it works...
2. And check if `type: "GET"` is correct, at [jquery handbook](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)...
3. And XML request? What you whant to send to the ajax-webservice? I notsee in your code...